# Php sql update doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

Omg this is interesting question i got ok, i have a code:

```
function Rotuse($building){
global $lang, $wg_village, $db;
$village_id=$wg_village->id;
includelang("musu"); //kisau nagus
$parse=$lang; //kisau nagus
$rs1zn=6400;
$rs2zn=6650;
$rs3zn=5940;
$rs4zn=1340;

$parse["rs1"]=$rs1zn;
$parse["rs2"]=$rs2zn;
$parse["rs3"]=$rs3zn;
$parse["rs4"]=$rs4zn;

if(isset($_POST['uzsakyti1'])){
    if($wg_village->rs1>=$rs1zn && $wg_village->rs2>=$rs2zn && $wg_village->rs3>=$rs3zn && $wg_village->rs4>=$rs4zn){
        //$sql="UPDATE wg_villages SET rs1=rs1-'".$rs1zn."', rs2=rs2-$rs2zn, rs3=rs3-$rs3zn, rs4=rs4-$rs4zn WHERE id=$village_id";
        $sql="UPDATE wg_villages SET rs1=100 WHERE id=80271";
        $db->setQuery($sql);
        $db->query();

    }else{
        echo "resursu nera";
    }
}



$parse['id']=$building->index;
return parsetemplate(gettemplate('rotuse_body'), $parse);
}
```

And sql update here doesn't work  BUT IF  i put same code to new file and acces it directly it works example:

```
    <?php
$db1= @mysql_connect('localhost', 'login', 'password') or die(mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db('vnzn') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');

$rs1azn=29700;
$rs2azn=33250;
$rs3azn=32000;
$rs4azn=6700;
$village_id=80271;
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<br/><input width="80" type='submit' height='20' value='{uzsakyti_svente}' name='uzsakyti1'></form><br/>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['uzsakyti1'])){
//mysql_query("UPDATE wg_villages SET rs1=rs1-$rs1zn, rs2=rs2-$rs2zn, rs3=rs3-$rs3zn, rs4=rs4-$rs4zn WHERE id=$village_id");
mysql_query("UPDATE wg_villages SET rs1=100 WHERE id=80271");
echo "ideta!";
var_dump($rs4azn);

}


exit; 






?>
```

It works i dont simply understand why, whats wrong with this code?

**EDIT VAR DUMP:**

Tried var dump $db i got this:

```
object(og_database)#1 (13) {["_sql"]=> string(45) "UPDATE wg_villages SET rs1=100 WHERE id=80271" ["_errorNum"]=> int(0) ["_errorMsg"]=> string(0) "" ["_table_prefix"]=> string(3) "wg_" ["_resource"]=> resource(5) of type (mysql link) ["_cursor"]=> bool(true) ["_debug"]=> int(0) ["_limit"]=> int(0) ["_offset"]=> int(0) ["_ticker"]=> int(0) ["_log"]=> array(0) { } ["_nullDate"]=> string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00" ["_nameQuote"]=> string(1) "`" }
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Im asking why in first case code sql update doesn't work and second works when i put same code in to file and acces it directlly

Comment: @John in the second code it works perfectlly but in first code it doesn't work and now mysql erros not displaying

Comment: "same code works in another file" they aren't the same code. The first looks like you're using the Joomla! database API and the second is deprecated MySQL lib.

Comment: @MrCode no im using custom cms and this is not joomla in the second case i added post button in 1 file but that is not a problem in frist file that button is in tpl file so

Comment: Well you need to look at the `$db` class to find out how to get the MySQL error from it.

Comment: Edit added var dump db